# Setting cookies in AIOHTTPTransport doesn't work

Tags: cookies, python-requests, graphql, aiohttp, gql

I'm trying to set cookies in the transport to execute a query using [gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql).
This works when I use `RequestsHTTPTransport` but not when I use `AIOHTTPTransport`.
The cookie needs to be present in the POST request. In case it's not present, the client gets redirected to the login page.
So if I'm using `requests` library directly, it should look like this:

```
cookies = authenticate(url, username, password)

json = { 'query' : '{ queryName { id }}' }

r = requests.post(url, json=json, cookies=cookies)
```

This works:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport

cookies=authenticate(url, username, password).get_dict()
transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url=url, timeout=900, cookies=cookies)

with Client(
    transport=transport,
#     fetch_schema_from_transport=True,
    execute_timeout=1200,
) as client:
    query = gql('''
        query {
            queryName { id } 
        }
    ''')
    result = client.execute(query)
    print(result)
```

This redirects me to the login page.

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport

cookies=authenticate(url, username, password).get_dict()
transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=url, timeout=900, cookies=cookies)

async with Client(
    transport=transport,
#     fetch_schema_from_transport=True,
    execute_timeout=1200,
) as client:
    query = gql('''
        query {
            queryName { id } 
        }
    ''')
    result = await client.execute(query)
    print(result)
```

I need to send the same cookies for uploading a file via graphQL which is why I need to use `AIOHttpTransport`. How do I send cookies the same way as in requests?

Note: Tried sending via `extra_args` but that didn't work.

Comment: Is this raising an error or silently failing? If it's raising an error, could you include it in the question?